I am unable to import Demo Data into my wordpress site
I need help please. I am experiacing an issue importing a demo data to my website.
I have purchased a theme from envato-Market then installed it on my website. the installation was done with no issue. also, i installed the required pluggins and my wordpress is up to date.
when i tried to import the demo, it keeps giving me an error. i am not sure how solve this.
enter image description here
enter image description here
I have searched on youtube, google but i did not find anything.
